# How to setup and start to use google test framework on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, unit-testing, googletest

I have read many articles and tips explaining how to setup the Google Test (c++) framework for `visual studio/eclipse/xcode` but I couldn't find any article about how to set it up on Mac OS without using an IDE.

How can I use Google Test on Mac OS's terminal without referring to any fancy IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for installing google test in Mac OS X

[How to install GTest on Mac OS X with homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852631/how-to-install-gtest-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew/42707478#42707478).

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to use [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852631/how-to-install-gtest-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew) or compile it from sources and install.